# App crashes sporadically when dismissing a presented UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Over the last few months we are facing the following issue intermittently in the app we are developing.

The App: It's a fairly complex iOS app with a tabbar-based navigation developed in Swift. It has a good number of pushes and presentations.

The issue: We sporadically encounter app crashes when presented view controllers are dismissed. These crashes are not reproducible, and you cannot find a scenario where this will definitely happen. The app does not crash indicating a line in our code. It is observed in various versions of both iOS 8 and iOS 9 devices. We never get any log pertaining to the crash.

[image: Crash State Screen Shot]

[image: Crash State Screen Shot 2]

As seen in the images, there's not much to go on with. But, on constant observation of crashes over the months, we've noticed something on the Thread 1 in the left bar of the Xcode window. The stack leading to the crash will always end with [UINavigationController viewWillAppear:]

Also, as seen in the stack is a line indicating '_CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER...' which made us suspect that an NSNotification selector is being called on a deallocated class. For this, we made sure that we removed all NSNotification observers in all classes before deallocations and also had logs in deinit methods of every class and made sure they were deallocating when required. This still didn't solve the problem.

Can somebody please help us with this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using the Zombies tool in instruments? I have seen similar issues in the past where the app was calling out to a released object, and this allowed me to identify the specific item.

Comment: How are you dismissing the presented view controllers?  Are they dismissing themselves or are you using a delegate pattern?   You should use a delegate for the presented view controller so that it can "request" to be dismissed.  If you are using a delegate, then are your delegate properties declared as weak?

Comment: @YourAdHere: Yes, I profiled the app using the Zombies tool. I discovered that a respondsToSelector: call was made to some ViewController [which is deallocated] which is not directly associated with the VC that's been dismissed. I've made sure I've removed all notification observers in every class before deallocation. What other reasons can there be for a released object to be called? Can you throw me some light on that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a delegate pattern?  If you are, then the delegate properties should always be declared as weak.  I am guessing you have a strong reference to a delegate property somewhere and a controller that uses notifications isn't getting deallocated.

Comment: No, a delegate pattern is not used to dismiss all controllers. We have used that only in situations where the presented view controller needs to be dismissed by a trigger from the controller from which it was presented.
And, yes, delegates are always weak all through the app.